How to hedge an options portfolio in hft settings?
Suppose that you are quoting multiple option strikes on multiple levels and getting hit very often. Such trading possesses a challenge from a risk management perspective. To stay delta neutral you need to hedge after each fill, which is not practical due to costs, you would need to use taker orders (cross the spread) to quickly follow the changes in total position.
You can try to hedge only after a certain value of delta is reached, but sometimes futures contract notional value exceeds the option value by a lot, so you can hedge with the futures only after the total portfolio delta becomes larger than the futures contract notional. This still puts you at risk while you are waiting for the position to reach this certain level.
My goal is to eliminate the risk from fast increase in underlying assets volatility, but textbook solutions do not really help in such settings. How does one deal with hft (up to 1 min until the position is closed) option delta/vega hedging in practice? any research that I can read on this topic?

You could probably see what firms such as Flow Traders or Optiver are doing.

I don't think that this info is public.
